# How do I get [] instead of {} in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am fairly new to js/nodejs and I am working on a little webscraper.

I have an array called `const itemList = [];` and a variable `const id = url.split(substring)[1]` which i use to get what i need from an url. Then I do `itemList.push({id});`
The Output looks like this

```
[
  { id: '330711' }, { id: '328921' },
  { id: '329362' }, { id: '328857' },
  { id: '321511' }, { id: '328897' },
  { id: '342074' }, { id: '341684' },
  { id: '341489' }, { id: '343365' },
  { id: '330711' }, { id: '340324' },
  { id: '342074' }, { id: '342923' },
  { id: '342863' }, { id: '344111' },
  { id: '343005' }, { id: '328857' },
  { id: '328897' }, { id: '328921' },
  { id: '343021' }, { id: '329362' },
  { id: '340047' }
]
```

But what I need is something like

```
[
  ['330711'],['328921'],
  ['329362'],['328857'],
  ['321511']
]
```

So basically, I need to get rid of the "id:" part and [] instead of {}. I don't know what to search for, so I am hoping someone cant get me on the right path here :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `data.map(({ id }) => [id])`

Comment: change `itemList.push({id});` to `itemList.push([id]);`

Comment: change `itemList.push({id})` to `itemList.push([id])`

Comment: Are you sure you want a 2d array?

Comment: If the inner arrays always have one element, are those arrays really required? Why not have just `["330711", "328921", "329362",...]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with `.map` method of `Array`:

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const data = [
  { id: '330711' }, { id: '328921' },
  { id: '329362' }, { id: '328857' },
  { id: '321511' }, { id: '328897' },
  { id: '342074' }, { id: '341684' },
  { id: '341489' }, { id: '343365' },
  { id: '330711' }, { id: '340324' },
  { id: '342074' }, { id: '342923' },
  { id: '342863' }, { id: '344111' },
  { id: '343005' }, { id: '328857' },
  { id: '328897' }, { id: '328921' },
  { id: '343021' }, { id: '329362' },
  { id: '340047' }
];

const mappedData = data.map(item => [item.id])

console.log(mappedData)
```

Good Luck...